# Apps using Google Apps Script not working properly in Google Chrome version 44

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-apps-script

In the company where I work, we have developed a lot of GAS tools used on a daily basis to capture information in order to portrait in QlikView or Google Spreadsheets, Sites, etc. However, since last week the tools are not loading properly, it appears that is related to Google Chrome version 44 because on version 43 is working fine.

Below you can find a really simple code that I tried but still not working:

Code.gs file:

```
function doGet(){
  var template=  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('transactions.html');
  var dateNew = new Date()
  var date = new Date(dateNew.getFullYear(),dateNew.getMonth(),dateNew.getDate()-1)
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  template.msg = ""
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
function doPost(e){
  Logger.log(new Date())
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('transactions.html');
  template.msg = e.parameter.kpiinfo
  template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

transactions.html

<?= msg ?>
<form action="<?= action ?>" method="post">
    <td><input type="text" name="kpiinfo"></td>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Current Behavior:** 
When I load the tool I can see the form (the text box and submit button) then I type anything and click the submit button. The submitted text appears a longs with the text box and the submit button (everything is fine so far) but when I click submit the reloaded form is empty (nor message, nor text box, nor submit button)

I have tried the different sandboxmodes: 
a) If I use Native the form is displayed but the submit buttons does not work at all.
b) If I use Emulated no form is displayed

**Expected behavior**
The applications made were able to submit the data a lot of times in a row.

Please note that we have several tools similar like this and are experiencing the same behavior. (The tools are being used by around 60 to 100 users so its crucial for the business).

I will appreciate if you know the solution regarding this issue. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation.

I used

```
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

instead of

```
.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.EMULATED)
```

Link [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/sandbox-mode).

Comment: This is not working. I have used IFRAME and the first time it does load the form properly and allows me to submit information but in the second time that I want to submit the information the reloaded page is on blank.

This was working the last week and then when the Google Chrome was upgraded to version 44 stopped working

Comment: Also, I have added  issue in this link: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5255 in case you want to review it.

Comment: This is the link of the app if you want to test it

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwXdIVqx6QOa9QtRf0pHHDBNyEZ7ApCeJaQdZ6pYPg/dev